# Amazing algorithms for image processing

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I have recently came across a great image processing [algorithm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NcIJXTlugc) called [Seam Carving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seam_carving). 
It uses graphs (Shortest Path algorithm) to do its job.

What other amazing algorithms are out there worth looking at?

I'm not talking about the majority of boring matrix based ones, rather something you could never think about before you came across it, just like this one.

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow wasn't made for these types of questions :(  It was very narrowly made and specified specifically for code and programming problems/questions with non-subjective answers.

Comment: More specifically, this falls to the "your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers" category of [don't ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: Oh. I just gave an example of what I'm looking for. I would say it's mind challenging like many questions here. And I don't know where to ask such questions. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is offtopic I'm going to answer ;)

In [this page](http://www.scriptol.com/programming/graphic-algorithms.php) you can find algorithms which:

- Depixelize an image
- Color a black and white image
- Restore a picture or make a HDR (whatever that means...)
- Turn a photo into an hand-drawn like image
- Seam carving
- Remove objects
- Compose a picture
- Beautify a face